# How do I get all the list of assets present in the AEM DAM

Tags: aem-6

We have assets api to fetch the list, but for that we need to provide AEM user credentials.

Do we have any interface, to fetch all the assets list from the dam just the way get all the pages using page manager.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can use JCR's QueryManager API and your specific query in conjunction. 
Below is a sample servlet which lists all the Assets below path - ***/content/dam/we-retail/en/features***

```java
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.query.Query;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryManager;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryResult;
import javax.jcr.query.Row;
import javax.jcr.query.RowIterator;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component(immediate = true, service = Servlet.class, property = { "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
        "sling.servlet.paths=" + "/bin/learning/assetlister" })
public class AssetListerServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    // Generated serialVersionUID
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7762806638577908286L;

    // Default logger
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    // Instance of ResourceResolver
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

    // JCR Session instance
    private Session session;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) {

        try {

            // Getting the ResourceResolver from the current request
            resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();

            // Getting the session instance by adapting ResourceResolver
            session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

            QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
            String queryString = "SELECT * FROM [dam:Asset] AS asset WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(asset ,'/content/dam/we-retail/en/features')";
            Query query = queryManager.createQuery(queryString, "JCR-SQL2");

            QueryResult queryResult = query.execute();

            response.getWriter().println("--------------Result-------------");

            RowIterator rowIterator = queryResult.getRows();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.nextRow();
                response.getWriter().println(row.toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (resourceResolver != null) {
                resourceResolver.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Similary using your specific requirement, you can use this logic in a component, service etc. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks. This might work. i totally forgot that we have query builder. Will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a python solution, [here](https://github.com/ashokkumarta/dampy) is a python tool that I created to connect to AEM DAM and perform most DAM operations, including [listing](https://github.com/ashokkumarta/dampy#list) of all DAM assets or assets under a given path